# Python replace using regex

Tags: python, regex

Does anyone know how to replace all ocurences of '<\d+' regex with '\r\n<\d+', for example

```
"<20"
```

should be transformed to

```
"\r\n<20"
```

but

```
"> HELLO < asassdsa"
```

shuld be untouched

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "<20"
>>> output = re.sub(r'<(?=\d)', r'\r\n<', str)
>>> output
'\r\n<20'
```

Comment: Why not go all the way and put the entire regex into the lookahead?

Comment: @Tim: That's what I thought. Also, maybe we shouldn't encourage the use of `str` as a variable name, although I always fail to find a better name :(

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
def replace(value):
  return re.sub(r'(<\d)', r'\r\n\1', value)
```

Or using lookahead:

```
import re
def replace(value):
  return re.sub(r'(?=<\d)', r'\r\n', value)
```