# Pattern matching and extracting it in the string occurrences

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How can I match a pattern and extract in between particular expressions of a string ? here in between `${` and  `}`

```
string = '''${data1}, ${data2}, ${data3}... '''
```

so my question is how can I extract `data1,data2 .... in the entire string?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Question is not clear and not well formatted.

Comment: you can use regex for this one. @Techielife

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one with the help of `regex`.

```
In [105]: import re

In [106]: m = re.findall('\${(.+?)}', string)

In [107]: m
Out[107]: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohit : One more doubt ,if i want to do any manipulation on that data and replace it in the string again , how can i achieve it?

Comment: Hey @Techielife you can you `re.sub` for replacing.

Comment: Refer this one for this :  [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192416/python-replace-using-regex)

Comment: i tried re.sub('\${=(.+?)}>', '\<c:out value = "${ (.+?) " />', string ) , but the data1,data2 and data3 variables  are being ignored

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: see: this      '''string = '''${data1}, ${data2}'''  should be changed to  '''string = '''<c:out value = " ${data1}"/>, <c:out value = " ${data2}"/>''''

Comment: m = re.findall('\${(.+?)}', string)

m = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']

output = ''

for i in m:
    st ='<c:out value = " ${'+i+'}"/>'
    output+=st

output='<c:out value = " ${data1}"/><c:out value = " ${data2}"/><c:out value = " ${data3}"/>'